# How does the Input Shape change model architecture?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm getting different results for the following two situations:

Example 1: Training data has shape (batch_size, n_steps) and the model is:

```
model_dense = tf.keras.Sequential([
   tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])
```

Example 2: My training data has shape (batch_size, n_steps, 1) and the model has the shape

```
model_dense = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=[n_steps, 1]),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])
```

Example 2 trains much better. Both models have n_steps+1 trainable parameters, and I thought the flatten layer for example 2 would simply flatten the channel dimension and therefore make it equivalent to Example 1. I think I'm missing something simple.

Answer (score 0):

In Example 1, the data is fed directly into a Dense layer without any specified input shape, meaning the model will infer the input shape from the training data. Here, each timestep is treated as a separate feature.

In Example 2, you explicitly define the input shape and include a Flatten layer before the Dense layer. This layer reshapes the data from a 3D tensor to a 2D tensor, where the first dimension is the batch size. Despite the flattening operation making the data structurally similar to Example 1, the explicit input_shape could be making the model initialization and training slightly different.